# How to check menu item class in Walker_Nav_Menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom two level menu in WordPress. There is an upper level and when you hover over the items, a submenu appears. Two menu items in the submenu have a button that is not in the other submenus. These two paragraphs have a "browse all" class. I need to check this class in Walker_Nav_Menu and add a custom button to the submenu. How can I check for class "browse all"?
In my code I'm creating a wrapper for ul.sub-menu. I need to check if there is a "browse all" class in the element in order to add a button to this wrapper. Such a button will only be in items with the "browse all" class.

```js
class My_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function start_lvl( & $output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    if ($depth == 0) {
      $output. = "\n$indent<div class='sub-menu__depth-1'><ul class='sub-menu sub-menu__main'>\n";
    } else {
      $output. = "\n$indent<ul class='sub-menu'>\n";
    }
  }

  function end_lvl( & $output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    if ($depth == 0) {
      $output. = "$indent</ul> <
        /div>\n";
    } else {
      $output. = "$indent</ul>\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Below is an example of how it should be:

```js
class My_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array())
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        if ($depth == 0) {
            $output .= "\n$indent<div class='sub-menu__depth-1'><ul class='sub-menu sub-menu__main'>\n";
        } else {
            $output .= "\n$indent<ul class='sub-menu'>\n";
        }
    }
    function end_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array())
    {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        if ($depth == 0) {
    //here, a button appears outside the sub-menu if the navigation element has the class "browse all"
            $output .= "$indent</ul>
    <a>Browse All</a>        
    </div>\n";
        } else {
            $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that directly in `start_lvl` or `end_level` - because those only create the wrapping UL. But that one doesn't have the classes you are looking for, those are on the actual navigation items, and those are processed/rendered in `start_el` and `end_el`.

But I suppose you could add a property to the class, an array - and in that one you keep the info, whether the current (sub-)menu of the specific depth requires these additional elements to be added, or not.

```
class My_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

  private $needsCustomButtons = [];

  function start_lvl( & $output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    $this->needsCustomButtons[$depth] = false;
    
    // rest of the stuff that needs doing here
  }

  public function start_el( &$output, $data_object, $depth = 0, $args = null, $current_object_id = 0 ) {
    // stuff

    $classes   = empty( $menu_item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $menu_item->classes;
    $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $menu_item->ID;

    if(in_array('browse-all', $classes)) {
      $this->needsCustomButtons[$depth] = true;
    }

    // more stuff here

  }

  function end_lvl( & $output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {
    // if $this->needsCustomButtons[$depth] is true here, then you know
    // your two extra nav items need adding, so concatenate them to
    // $output here, before the closing `</li>` tag gets added.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it's a bit different from what I need. I have already added classes to two elements in the admin panel. I now need to make a check, if they are, then add a button. I added an example to the question.

Comment: I don't see how that is supposed to clarify anything. That still seems to be the exact same requirement as the original one.

Comment: _"I have already added classes to two elements in the admin panel."_ - no one said anything else, or doubted that. Those classes will be found in the `$classes` array inside the `start_el` method (after that default code found in there has run), and that is the place to check for them.

Comment: Now I have an error $menu_item Undefined variable $menu_item

Comment: Do I need to change $data_object to $menu_item?

Comment: When I wrote `// stuff` at the start of the `start_el` function, that was supposed to mean that you should take over the other stuff the original method does in that place. So yes, you need that `$menu_item = $data_object;`, for the rest of the method to be able to work with `$menu_item`.